# Template renderer from WinJS analog in XAML/C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

In WinJS application `itemTemplate` property of listview can accept a function in which i can create elements manually.

What is the analog for this approach in XAML/C# applications?

I know about DataTemplate selectors, but I need to create items manually, I want rid off templates because of performance.

Comment: You want the solution of the template creation function in c# so that you can create dynamic templates as in winJs ?? I am not so clear about the question is it so :) ??

Comment: @Anobik yes, but i don't want to use databinding in created control

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen DataTemplateSelector? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/The-DataTemplateSelector-93e46ad7

Comment: thank you, I know about DataTemplate selectors, but I need to create items manually, I want rid off templates because of performance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make a CustomControl inheriting from ItemsControl.

```
   public class BuildingComparer : ItemsControl
      {}
```

There, you will find some methods to override:

```
 protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        var container = new ContentPresenter();           
        //Do Stuff
        return container;            
    }
```

And you have access to the Items property so you can paint the elements whenever the SizeChanged event occurs, you can call to a Method wich manually paints all the elements.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this in C# / XAML, you need to bind the ItemsControl's `ItemsSource` property to a property that creates the items for you.

Example XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SourceProperty}" />
```

Example DataContext:

```
public IEnumerable SourceProperty
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TextBlock(new Run("First"));
        yield return new TextBlock(new Run("Second"));
        yield return new TextBlock(new Run("Third"));
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you absolutely must avoid all databinding (I'm not sure why you would), you can assign the `ItemsSource` in the codebehind:

Updated XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" />
```

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = SourceProperty;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I need a way to generate items for ListView so I can take advantage of item virtualization

Comment: @Alexander so use a ListView instead of an ItemsControl? The same principles apply. Do you need UI virtualization or data virtualization? If you need data virtualization, does it need to be sequential or random access? There's not really enough information here to provide good guidance.